# How to Maintain Activity state on any action (home press , back press , overview press)

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am Working on Device lock Application . for that I need to maintain my Lock activity's state on any action.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [lifecycle aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) like `viewmodel` that stay around even after view has been destroyded and recreated check out [their patterns here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54)